# When I select the payment method and return back to the site, cart is cleared

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, payment-methods

When I select the payment method and return back to the site, cart is cleared.

I am testing this on Mollie payments but it works fine for all payments. If I go to the payment page, select a payment method, click "Place Order" and return without paying, then my selected products will be reset.

Is there some way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you place an order place the cart is converted to order and that cart will be inactive, so once the order place a new cart is created. so In your case when the order place and then payment get fails the cart gets empty by default.

So You can not prevent a cart from being clear as the cart is converted into an order. You can however set the cart as active again in case of failure

Check below reference

http://ka.lpe.sh/2011/12/31/magento-getting-back-shopping-cart-items-after-order-fails/

Comment: but this is magento 1 solution